# Generate a Maven site for a released artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

I have a Java library that I release as a Maven artifact, using the `maven-release-plugin`. I want to have a separate Maven project responsible for producing the site for this library, so that I can make changes to the site's content (e.g. FAQs, tutorials, etc.) without having to re-release the library.

The only data I wish to incorporate from the library itself is:

- the Javadocs
- any source-based reports (e.g. coverage or FindBugs reports)
- the version number (manually updating this in the site project would be OK)

These items will need to be generated as reports when the library project is built and released. I need to somehow make these available to the site project so it can incorporate the data in the site it produces. Is this possible?

Comment: Why is it not possible to update the site without deploying ? mvn site-deploy ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained. I wanted to do tagged releases of both my site and my code. Hence I tend to use the release plugin, which currently then deploys my site. I also wanted my site to reflect the current released version of my library, rather than mentioning `-SNAPSHOT` at every opportunity.

Comment: In this case you should deploy the site only if you changed the code and deploy with the help of the release plugin. If your site does not represent the released state of your project the configuration in Maven sounds wrong. Or i misunderstand what you like to achieve.

Comment: @khmarbaise I've edited my question - I hope that makes it easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve and why.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the [Configuring the Site Descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html), by linking to the external URL for supporting your requirement to change some site contents. e.g.

```
<project>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <links>
        <item name="FAQs" href="http://.../faq.html"/>
        <item name="Tutorials" href="http://.../tutorial.html"/>
    </links>
    ...
  </body>
  ...
</project>
```

Even this workaround may help you to change the contents, I also would like to encourage you to keep all contents and release them together with the same version.

I hope this may help.